# More info about J-link v8

Tags: arm, jtag

I have a J-link v8 and want to use it, but I can't find its name in Segger homepage, I want to know what ARM core it support and is it support BeagleBone or RPi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you need should be on [this](http://www.segger.com/jlink_base.html) page, the note at the bottom of the page refers to hardware revision 8 and up which I assume refers to the V8 you have.

In particular the following CPUs are supported:
Any ARM7/9/11, Cortex-A5/A8/A9, Cortex-M0/M1/M3/M4, Cortex-R4, RX610, RX621, RX62N, RX62T, RX630, RX631, RX63N

While both the CPUs for the Beaglebone (Cortex-A8) and RPi (ARM11) are supported, I don't think that either board includes the JTAG port by default, you may need to solder pins on to make this available.  Some information on the RPi [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=16199), the Beaglebone [here](http://www.supermicros.org/1/post/2013/07/jtag-and-emulation-on-the-beaglebone-black.html).